# Randomize filenames but keep extensions

Tags: python

I am trying to randomize filenames in a directory. The problem is that the extension disappears after renaming. What do I need to change in order to new filenames have their original extensions?

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from random import choice, randint, random
import os

def randomize_files(dir):
    for f in os.listdir(dir):
        path = os.path.join(dir, f)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            newpath = os.path.join(dir, ''.join([choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(randint(5, 8))]))
            os.rename(path, newpath)

randomize_files("/tmp/tset21")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that's normal: if you rename file "abc.txt" to "efg", you remove the extension. `os.rename` is the equivalent of `mv` in bash

Instead, what you can do is something like that:

```
extension = path.split('.')[-1]
new_name = generate_random_name()
os.rename(path, new_name + '.' + extension)
```